# How to raise number of parameters in cventry?

Tags: moderncv

Currently I am using the `moderncv` class and the `banking` style. I would like to increase the number of parameters which I can insert in the `\cventry{}` command. By default it's only 7 with first argument being optional.

I guess I have to reshape the command using `\renewcommand` such as:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]
```

Is it further possible to use manual line breaks between the different parameters of `\cventry`? So, for instance, I would like use a line break between parameter 1 and 2, but it should be manual. Any suggestions?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry} 
\name{John}{Doe} 
\title{Resume title} 
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890} 
%\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em] 
\begin{document} 
\makecvtitle 
\section{Education} 
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: While helping is pleasure and solving a problem is fun, recreating the problem/starting from scratch would certainly be a nightmare. Please provide some code in the form of [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. As the argument `1` is optional, you have to explain the phrase `between parameter 1 and 2` precisely. I feel that you mean between `2` and `3`. Please clarify.

Comment: @HarishKumar Ok, my idea is to make it possible to include more than 6 parameters (default). Of course, it is possible to add a seventh {}, howevever, the spacing is bigger - this is due to the fact that 6 parameters is the maximum. So, is it possible to increase the maximum number of parameters for ´\cventry´?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible. Only thing is you have to tell where the extra entry should be inserted and what should be its format.

Comment: @HarishKumar Secondly, I would like to make it possible to position the single parameters as I want. For instance, if the content for one parameter is very huge, it might be a nice work around to put it simply in the next line. The default setting only allows you to use half of the space because it is like a two-column-table.

Comment: @HarishKumar Cool!! So, I would like to have a extra parameter at the end (bottom right in the pdf). Formatting: normal, i.e. no bolt nor italic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra arguments to `\cventry` with necessary formatting. Here is a sample, tweak this as you wish. This is only an illustration.

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[8][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \ifx&#8&%
    \else{\par\noindent\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedleft #8}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}
  }
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[8][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{\small#7}}\fi%
  \ifx&#8&%
    \else{\par\noindent\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedleft #8}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}
  }

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors}{Extra}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. one additional question though:
the "extra"-argument should have the same formatting as the "majors"-argument. How do I adapt the code to get this?
i.e. for the additional parameters the formatting (size, spacing etc.) should be exactly the same as for the "majors"-parameter.

Comment: @Phil Use `\small#8`.

Comment: I modified the code that way and it is working, too:
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[8][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
      {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
      {#7} & \\ {#8} & \\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  }

Comment: adjusting the code by `\small#8` the spacing is not constant.

Comment: regarding my solution: there comes up another problem if I do not use all 8 parameters. since it is like a table, empty cells are shown as empty and leaving a lot of space in the CV. is there a solution to hide unused space?

Comment: @Phil: Use `\renewcommand*{\cventry}[8][.25em]{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
{\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\%
{\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
{#7} &
\ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\\ {#8} & \\}%
\end{tabular*}%
}`.

Comment: Great!! One last point: sometimes I use only 3 parameters of the ´\cventry´, i.e., till "degree". However, with the new ´\renewcommand´ there is now an additional line which remains empty. Is it possible to fix this? It should be an ´\ifthenelse´-command i guess. However, when I use it the whole third line disappears.

Comment: @Phil You have to use `\ifthenelse` for `4`, `5` and `7` too.

Comment: I changed it, however, the problem remains unsolved. I still get an output for a ´\cventry´ with only three parameters (3,4,5) which actually shows me an additional line for parameter 7.
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[9][.25em]{% 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% 
\ifthenelse{\equal{\bfseries #4}{}}{}{{\bfseries #4}} & \ifthenelse{\equal{\bfseries #5}{}}{}{{\bfseries #5}} \\%  
\ifthenelse{\equal{\itshape #3}{}}{}{{\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}}} & {\itshape #2}\\% 
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{{#7}} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\\ {#8} & \\}%
\end{tabular*}% 
}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed it, however, now the total third line disappears...

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[9][.25em]{% 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% 
{\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5} \\% 
{\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\% 
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\\ {#8} & \\}%
\end{tabular*}% 
}
```